# mapping a class to JSon in Angular

Tags: typescript, angular5

I have a class

```
export class User {
constructor(public firstname:string,
public lastname:string
public email:string
public password:string){}
}
```

I want to send it as a Json but the `User` data should be a Json object inside another object. The final json should look as follows

```
{
"external-profile":{
"firstname":"something",
"lastname":"something",
"email":"some@something",
"password":"something"
}

}
```

How could I do this in Angular? I tried the following two approaches but they don't work

1) creating an object of type `User` and doing `JSON.stringify(user)` produces

```
{
    "firstname":"something", <-- not embedded in external-profile
    "lastname":"something",
    "email":"some@something",
    "password":"something"
    }
```

2) creating another class UserProfiles as follows

```
class UserProfile{
constructor(public externalProfile:User){} //I can't use hypen separated variable names in Typescript it seems.
}
```

the above produces if I create an object of type `UserProfile` and `JSON.stringify` it.

```
{
    "externalProfile":{  <-- I want external-profile, not externalProfile
    "firstname":"something",
    "lastname":"something",
    "email":"some@something",
    "password":"something"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable and parameter names can't contain special characters, but class fields can if you quote them, you just can't use the syntactic sugar of constructor parameters to fields:

```
class UserProfile{
    'external-profile': User
    constructor(externalProfile:User){
        this["external-Profile"] = externalProfile;
    }
}
```

You don't need another class though you could just call:

```
JSON.stringify({ 'external-profile': user })
```